# How to center the view on the "Time Cursor" in the Video Sequence Editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, timeline

I have three markers in the timeline, and I am working in one of these three areas in the sequencer around the 3rd mark:

[image]

I try to use the first marker in the timeline, so that the sequencer jumps to that position without having to zoom out in the sequencer and look for that 1st mark manually and then zoom in  around it.

There is a menu entry 'jump to the previous marker', but then only the time cursor (green line) jumps and gets out of sight, but the sequencer keeps showing the same area I was working in.

Is there a way to tell the sequencer to pan to the area where the green line is? I want the whole view to jump to where the previous marker is, and not only the green line.

Comment: Not sure I understood the question, but I guess you're looking for "Jump to the next marker" function in the Marker menu (of any animation Editor). You can assign a shortcut to it by right clicking on it.

Comment: @thibsert Yes, but then the green line jumps and gets out of sight. But the sequencer keeps showing the same area. I want the view in the sequencer to jump, not only the green line. Or, is there a way to say "pan to the area where the green line is" to the sequencer?

Comment: Once the green line is on the desired marker, you can press Numpad 0 to center the view on it.

Comment: @thibsert Yes, I thought the same...

Comment: @thibsert You solved my question, thanks!  :)  Please write that comment as a short answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for "Jump to the next marker" function in the Marker menu (of any animation Editor). You can assign a shortcut to it by right clicking on it.

Once the Current frame (the green line) is on the desired marker, you can use Numpad 0 to center the view on it.